# How to find encoding method with encoded value?

Tags: encryption, encoding, numeric

I have 2 numeric values...
1. 50634031 (before encoding)
2. 7827165 (after encoding)

The value (1) is the initial value which is encoded with an unknown encoding method to the value (2).As I'm learning about encoding techniques regarding creating a validation mechanishm for an application,My question is that,can we find the encoding technique,so that I can encode another value say 50979163...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can guess which encoding method is used. But there will be an infinite number of mathematical calculations that can transform one single number to another single number.